# how to deal with exceptions on a Spring controller while generating a file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, io, outputstream

I've implemented a Spring controller that generates a PDF file, consuming my service layer. The problem is that when some exception is thrown during the execution of the method, even if I get the exception with a try-catch block, spring tries to resolve the view based on the current URL.

I honestly have no idea on what is causing this behavior.

```java
    @RequestMapping("/cliente")
    public void relatorioCliente(EdicaoMovimentacaoWrapper wrapper, @AuthenticationPrincipal Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            gerarReportService.relatorioParaCliente(wrapper.getContaId(), usuario);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO alguma coisa
        }
    }
```

the `relatorioParaCliente` method generates the PDF and exports it to the response's OutputStream.

Expected: the exception gets caught, the stack trace gets printed and nothing happens to the user.
Actual result: Spring redirects the user to `views/cliente.jsp`

**UPDATE**

I've tried changing the return type of the method so it looks like this now:

```java
    @RequestMapping("/cliente")
    public ModelAndView relatorioCliente(EdicaoCadastroMovimentacaoWrapper wrapper, @AuthenticationPrincipal Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            gerarReportService.relatorioParaCliente(wrapper.getContaId(), usuario);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ModelAndView("/contas/" + wrapper.getContaId());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But this has no effect on my code.
I suppose that this does not affect the code because the outputStream gets used on the service. take a look:

```java
@Service
public class ExportarReportPdfService {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletResponse res;

    public void exportar(List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList) throws IOException {

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList));

        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(res.getOutputStream()));

        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();

        configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true);

        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

        res.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
        res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=relatorio.pdf" );


        try {
            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new CriacaoReportException("Erro ao exportar para PDF");
        } finally {
            OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *... and nothing happens to the user.* I assume you are calling `/cliente` with a browser? The `GET` request has to be answered somehow. So doing nothing is not an option.

Comment: "doing nothing" was just an example, I intend to give the user some feedback (if you know a good way to do this I'd love your suggestions)

Comment: The idea is to remain on the same page whether the operation succeeds or not. 
If the file is generated correctly, the user gets the download.
If it fails the user gets a message that it failed.

I just can't find a way to do this appropriately.

Comment: If you want to display a page usually the return type of your method is `String` and you point your framework to some page or template. What web framework are you using? In Thymeleaf for example you would return the path to the template that should be rendered.

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC. I've already tried something similar in the past, but it didn't work, because when the file gets exported correctly it shouldn't redirect to another page. Let me test it again.

Comment: An easy solution would be to keep your method `void` and to **not** catch your exception. You already throw your own exception `CriacaoReportException`. Why write an [exception handler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) that reacts to your custom exception by displaying the desired error page?

Comment: Just tried it but it seems that my ExceptionHandler is not working for this exception. 
I'll check what's wrong and test it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the problem:

instead of Autowiring the response on the service and exporting the pdf from there, I generate a byteArray and return it to the controller:

```
@Service
public class ExportarReportPdfService {

    public byte[] exportar(List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList)  {

        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList));

        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));

        [OMITED CODE]

        try {
            exporter.exportReport();
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new CriacaoReportException("Erro ao exportar para PDF");
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller sends the response as a ResponseEntity :

```
        @RequestMapping("/geral")
        public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> relatorioAdministrador(EdicaoCadastroMovimentacaoWrapper wrapper, @AuthenticationPrincipal Usuario usuario) {

            byte[] arquivo = gerarReportService.relatorioParaAdmin(wrapper.getContaId(), usuario);

            return ResponseEntity
                    .ok()
                    .contentLength(arquivo.length)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=relatorio.pdf")
                    .body(new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(arquivo)));
        }
```

So if any exception occurs it will be caught in the `ExceptionHandler` as @cmoetzing explained in the comments:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(CriacaoReportException.class)
    public ModelAndView trataGeracaoRelatorio(CriacaoReportException exception) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```